# What does it mean that these outcome sets are dependent?

Tags: probability, statistics

Say we throw two dice. Firstly, we get 2 which is our set $A$. Secondly, we get 3 which is our set $B$. What does it mean for that these two sets are dependent?

$A = \{2\}$, $B = \{3\}$, sample space = $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$

Because $P(A \cap B)\neq P(B)P(A)$ Therefore $A$ & $B$ are dependent.

Comment: See [Independence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory))

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA As I understand is that two sets are independent if they do not affect the outcome of the other. So why does in this case A affect the outcome of B? (dependence, I guess(?))

Comment: Since it's a dice every side is available at every throw.

Comment: "*First we get 2 which is our set A*"... This seems off.  Do you mean to say you throw two dice in sequence and $A$ is the random variable corresponding to the result of the first die and $B$ is the random variable corresponding to the result of the second die?  Then yes, the random variables $A$ and $B$ are independent.  The sample space you refer to is not the sample space of the experiment as a whole but rather just the result of a single die.  If you want the sample space of the experiment as a whole that would be $\{(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),\dots,(1,6),(2,1),\dots,(6,5),(6,6)\}$

Comment: And here, the event that $A$ took the value of $2$ would have corresponded to $\{(2,1),(2,2),(2,3),(2,4),(2,5),(2,6)\}$ and similarly $B$ taking value three would have corresponded to $\{(1,3),(2,3),(3,3),\dots,(6,3)\}$.  The intersection here would have been $\{(2,3)\}$.  As for probabilities, $\frac{1}{6}\times\frac{1}{6}$ does indeed equal $\frac{1}{36}$

Comment: @JMoravitz Thank you, this cleared it up! So to summarize, it is a big difference in doing it in sequence and parallell?

Comment: Not at all.  Doing it parallel and doing it in sequence you still have the same description of the sample space as being *pairs* of die results.  Note also that if using two indistinguishable dice and throwing them at the same time it is better to *imagine* that the dice *were* in fact distinguishable (*e.g. a red die and a blue die*) so that we can use counting techniques to find probabilities, otherwise some of the outcomes in our sample space would occur at different rates than others.

Comment: *As I understand is that two sets are independent if they do not affect the outcome of the other.* Not quite: the correct question is whether the ***probability*** of the other's outcome is affected. I elaborate here: [independence intuition](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3906860/21813).

Answer (score 1):

Before you threw the dice you had

$P(A=2)=1/ 6$ and $P(B=3) = 1 /6$. Also $P((A=2)\cap(B=3))=1/36$.

The events are independent. It is irrelevant whether you throw one die twice or  two distinct dice at the same time.